# How find this value$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^22^{3n+1}}$

Tags: analysis

show  that:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(2n)!}{(n!)^22^{3n+1}}=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{1/2}?$$

this sum is from  other problem,if I solve this,then the other problem is solve it

Comment: Show that $$\frac 1{\sqrt{1-x}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2n)!}{n!^2}\left(\frac x4\right)^n$$ For other central-binomial series see [pi314.net](http://www.pi314.net/eng/hypergse11.php#x13-9300011)

Comment: I do not find this result. See my answer (there could very well be an overlook in my answer).

Comment: @mookid: comparing expansions with pari/gp :  $$\sqrt{1-x}= 1 - x/2 - x^2/8 - x^3/16 - 5x^4/128-\cdots$$  
$$1/\sqrt{1-x}= 1 + x/2 + 3x^2/8 + 5x^3/16 + 35x^4/128+\cdots$$

vector(6,n,binomial(2*n,n)/4^n) = [1/2, 3/8, 5/16, 35/128, 63/256, 231/1024]  
Anyway the derivative of the first one should be proportional to the second one...

Comment: @RaymondManzoni I don't see the bug. I don't have pari either. If you know where it is, thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** what is $\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$ when $f(x) = \sqrt{1-x}$?

---

Compute the first terms:
\begin{align}
f^{(0)}(x) &= \sqrt{1-x}\\
f^{(1)}(x) &= -\frac 12 (1-x)^{-1/2} \\
f^{(2)}(x) &= -\frac 14 (1-x)^{-3/2} \\
\end{align}

The exponent of $1-x$ in $f^{(n)}(x)$ is obviously $1/2 - n$. So when you derivate,
the front factor gets multiplied by $1/2 - n$ to get $f^{(n+1)}(x)$, and by $-1 $ because of the chain rule.

Hence the result is 
\begin{align}f^{(n+1)}(0) 
&= 1\times \left(\frac 12 - 0\right) \times \left(\frac 12 - 1\right)
\times \dots \times \left(\frac 12 - n\right) \times (-1)^{n+1} \\
&= \frac{1\times 3 \times \dots \times (2n-1)}{2^{n+1}} (-1)^n  \times (-1)^{n+1}
= -\frac{1\times 3 \times \dots \times (2n-1)}{2^{n+1}}\\
&= -\frac{(2n)!}{2^{n+1} 2\times 4 \times \dots \times 2n} = -\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n+1} n!} \end{align}

You can check that this is true for the first values:
\begin{align}
f^{(1)}(x) &= -\frac 12 = 1\times \frac 12 &\times (-1)^1 \\
f^{(2)}(x) &= -\frac 14 = 1\times \frac 12 \times \left(-\frac 12\right)
&\times (-1)^2  
\end{align}

Then, you must show that the series is convergent for $x=\frac 12$ and you will get:
\begin{align}
\sqrt{1-x} 
&= 1 + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n+1)}(0) }{(n+1)!}x^{n+1} \\
&= 1 - \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n+1} (n!)^2 (n+1)} x^{n+1}
\end{align}

---

Unfortunately, when evaluated in $\frac 12$, this does not make appear the desired sum, because of the factor $n+1$.

We can get rid of it just using tern by term derivation:
\begin{align}
-\frac 12 (1-x)^{-1/2} 
&=- \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n+1} (n!)^2} x^n\\
 (1-x)^{-1/2} 
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n} (n!)^2} x^n
\end{align}

And now we get, with $x=1/2$:
$$
 \left(1-\frac 12\right)^{-1/2} 
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2n)!}{2^{3n} (n!)^2} 
$$

Comment: I believe that something is amiss; the sum is $\sqrt{\frac12}$.

Comment: I don't find the error here, even if the result is wrong.

Comment: I get $$(1-x)^{1/2}=1-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(2k)!}{2^{2k+1}k!^2}\frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}$$ You are dividing by $n!$ instead of $(n+1)!$ on the $x^{n+1}$ term, it seems.

Comment: Shouldn't your denominator in $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n+1)}(0) }{n!} \left(\frac 12\right)^{n+1}$$ be $(n+1)!\;$ so that the derivative should give the correct result ? (robjohn found the same thing it seems! :-))

Comment: @RaymondManzoni thanks! I'll see if I can fix this easily.

Comment: @robjohn thanks! It seems I get the wrong sum... I think I should delete this message.

Comment: @mookid: It might be difficult to approach the answer using this function, but it is possible that your answer might be salvaged. If you can salvage it, that would be a benefit to the site. If you can't salvage it, then that indicates another path.

Comment: @robjohn An easy fix is possible, I added it in the end. Thanks again for tracking the error!

Comment: @mookid: somewhere in there, a factor of $2$ was dropped. The left side of the last line is $\sqrt2$ when it should be $\sqrt{\frac12}$. You have $$\sqrt{1-x} 
= 1 - \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n+2} (n!)^2 (n+1)} x^{n+1}$$ but the right side does not look like $1-\frac12x+\dots$

Comment: looks much better now :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Using the [generalized binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalised_binomial_theorem), we get
$$
\begin{align}
\left(1-x\right)^{-1/2}
&=1+\frac12x+\frac{\frac12\cdot\frac32}{2!}x^2+\frac{\frac12\cdot\frac32\cdot\frac52}{3!}x^3+\frac{\frac12\cdot\frac32\cdot\frac52\cdot\frac72}{4!}x^4+\dots\\[6pt]
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(2k-1)!!}{2^kk!}x^k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(2k)!}{2^{2k}k!^2}x^k\\
\end{align}
$$
Plug in $x=\frac12$ and check the result.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series). Try to rewrite $\bigg(\dfrac12\bigg)^\tfrac12$ as $\bigg(1-\dfrac12\bigg)^\tfrac12$ or as $\Big(1+1\Big)^{^{-\tfrac12}}$. Then expand, simplify the general term, and see what happens. :-$)$